# Requesting in use authorization shows no prompt

Tags: ios8, core-location

I have

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

and

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

defined in my Info.plist.

In my code I do

```
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And I don't get prompted on iOS8.

I did a clean reinstall in my simulator. On iOS7 without the 3 if block I get prompted.

Right after startUpdatingLocation I check `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` which is `0- kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`

How do I prompt iOS8 users?

Answer (score 0):

4 ios 8:  Need configure it in info.plist,

key name as "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" value as ""

key name as "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" value as ""

When you called:

```
[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

will be auto prompt.

Testing with simulator, you can click "Reset content and settings..." and prompt again.

Here is a demo : https://github.com/JNYJ/001PGWUcurrentWULF